# Function variable closure

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a simple slider code and I wanted to understand how the variable function closure is working...

```
(function($) {
var sliderUL = $('div.slider').css('overflow', 'hidden').children('ul'),
    imgs = sliderUL.find('img'),
    imgWidth = imgs[0].width, // 600
    imgsLen = imgs.length, // 4
    current = 1,
    totalImgsWidth = imgsLen * imgWidth; // 2400

$('#slider-nav').show().find('button').on('click', function() {
    var direction = $(this).data('dir'),
        loc = imgWidth; // 600

    // update current value
    **( direction === 'next' ) ? ++current : --current;
    // if first image
    if ( current === 0 ) {
        current = imgsLen;
        loc = totalImgsWidth - imgWidth; // 2400 - 600 = 1800
        direction = 'next';
    } else if ( current - 1 === imgsLen ) { // Are we at end? Should we reset?
        current = 1;
        loc = 0;
    }
    transition(sliderUL, loc, direction);**
});

function transition( container, loc, direction ) {
    var unit; // -= +=

    if ( direction && loc !== 0 ) {
        unit = ( direction === 'next' ) ? '-=' : '+=';
    }

    container.animate({
        'margin-left': unit ? (unit + loc) : loc
    });
}

})(jQuery);
```

In this part:

```
    $('#slider-nav').show().find('button').on('click', function() {
    var direction = $(this).data('dir'),
        loc = imgWidth; // 600

    // update current value
    ( direction === 'next' ) ? ++current : --current;

    // if first image
    if ( current === 0 ) {
        current = imgsLen;
        loc = totalImgsWidth - imgWidth; // 2400 - 600 = 1800
        direction = 'next';
    } else if ( current - 1 === imgsLen ) { // Are we at end? Should we reset?
        current = 1;
        loc = 0;
    }

    transition(sliderUL, loc, direction);
});
```

In the if ( current === 0) block, are the variables current, loc, and direction updated after being changed in the first block, then they are passed to the transition function below?

I take it that if the else if ( current - 1 === imgsLen ) is true, then current and loc are write over the previous values assigned to them, to then be passed into the transitions function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`direction` and `loc` are defined in the scope of your callback function for 'click'.  They are initialized every time you call that callback function -- at every click.  `direction` is initialized by the 'data-dir' associated to the button and `loc` is initialized to the current value of `imgWidth` (which is a variable defined in the scope of your main function).

After being initialized, `direction` and `loc` can be modify by your `if-else if` logic and they are then passed to the function `transition()`.  (Note that `sliderIU` is also passed to `transition()`, but it is not necessary since it has the scope of your main function and it could be used directly within `transition()` without being passed as parameter `container`.  However it might not be a bad idea to pass it as a parameter since it makes for clearer programming style when you can see from the arguments of a function on which values it is acting.)

The variable `current` which is used in the callback-click function is not defined in the scope of that callback-click function but has the main function scope (defined at the start of the main function).  This is necessary because you want to change its value --and remember the change-- each time the button is clicked.  The callback-click function is a *closure* since it has access (read+write) to the external variable `current`.  The variables `direction` and `loc` have nothing to do with closures; they are just variables that you pass to a function.

Answer (score 0):

The steps for the code that you've highlighted are as follows:
- Get the value for 'dir' from the button that was clicked
- Set default value of loc to the width of the image (imgWidth)
- If direction is 'next', then add 1 to current else subtract 1 from current

Now, at this point, we might have a situation where current may be either 0 or imgLen + 1. Either of these is not a good value. So we do the following
- If current is 0
    - set current to imgsLen (go to the last image)
    - set loc to max possible valid value
    - set direction = 'next'
- If current is beyond the last image
    - set current = 0 (go to the first image)
    - set loc to 0 (minimum possible valid value)
- Call the transition function with the updated values of arguments

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Yes!  That means that depeneding on the condition met, those variables will be set to those values, then those values are plugged into the transition slider. Thanks Amit!